# Should you say hour or hours in this type of sentence?

Tags: plural-forms

Being a non native speaker of English, this type of sentence always bites me:

> It was a pleasant four ***hours*** journey from Nashik to Pune.

Should it be *hour* or *hours*?

Comment: I would write "four-hour journey."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As kiamlaluno comments, the standard form is [a two-hour wait](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20two%20hour%20wait%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en), [three-man band](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20two%20hour%20wait%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2000,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22three-man%20band%22&oq=%22three-man%20band%22&gs_l=serp.3...12227.14285.4.14819.8.8.0.0.0.0.68.428.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.QcUdfNrrPWQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45373924,d.ZG4&fp=a9b59d972e620176&biw=1265&bih=826), [four-course meal](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22four-course%20meal%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)...

Although not everyone always bothers with the hyphen, you should include it if you want your *written* form to be above criticism. But *never* pluralise the "unit" (*two-hour, three-day, four-month, six-foot*, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

In this sentence, the phrase *four hour* (sometimes written as *four-hour*) acts as an adjective, and English adjectives do not have a plural form.

This type of adjective is called a **compound adjective**. They are commonly used when describing time and size (among other things).

Some other examples include:

- Three-hour tour
- Fifty-yard line
- Six-man team
- Five-mile run
- 2 Liter bottle
- Ten-Gallon hat

Comment: 4 hours is wrong?

Comment: @Sudhir: Oh ye of little faith! My answer, posted an hour before you asked that, says: ***never** pluralise the "unit"*.

Comment: @Sudhir: Yeah, "four-hours" as an adjective is incorrect.  So it would be "it was a pleasant four-hour trip."  Note however that this could be written as, "It was a pleasant trip that lasted four hours," in which "four hours" *is* correct.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this written – in published works – at least four different ways:

- (a) a four hour journey
- (b) a four-hour journey
- (c) a four hours journey
- (d) a four hours' journey

That all said, when looking for examples, it was relatively easy to find examples of formats (b) and (d), while examples of (a) and (c) were much harder to find, and seemed to come from less reliable sources. I would recommend using either (b) or (d) in writing.

It's hard to gauge which forms are preferred, because [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two%20day%20trip,two%20days%27%20trip&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) aren't much use here – there's just no way to check all possible usages (e.g., we could check *two hour trek, three hour tour, four mile hike, five day sojourn, six hour walk, seven day trip*, etc.).

In case anyone thinks (a) and (c) are not valid, don't argue with me, argue with the publishers of these books:

[image: example of form (a)]

[image: example of form (b)]

[image: example of form (c)]

[image: example of form (d)]

Comment: +1 for pointing out that "four hours' journey" is also possible (and that people often forget or misplace apostrophes).

Comment: I'd say that *a four hours' journey* is at best archaic, and has no place in a learners' website. The general principle of *number + hyphen + **singular** noun* works for everyone in all contexts, but how often has anyone ever written that they ate *a four courses' meal*? I wouldn't touch that with a ten feet's bargepole!

Comment: @Fumble: [This](http://books.google.com/books?id=eYHwXdNVxzMC&pg=PA173&dq=%22four+hours+walk%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kQxzUaC_E6X02wWRi4HACw&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBDgy#v=onepage&q=%22four%20hours%20walk%22&f=false) is not an archaic book. Neither is [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=knrvSpkURO4C&pg=PA53&dq=%22six+hours+drive%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Tg1zUaPXD8fErQG3-IH4CQ&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22six%20hours%20drive%22&f=false). The O.P. asked about a unit of time, not about a meal. And just because this is a learner's site doesn't mean I'm going to answer questions as if they are kindergarteners.

Comment: @ J.R.: Each to their own, but if I were a learner asking which of two alternatives was "correct", I'd rather be given a generic answer stating that one is *always* correct, and is used 99% of the time. I wouldn't particularly want to be distracted by being told about other permutations that occasionally (and imho wrongly) turn up here and there.

Comment: @Fumble: The risk you take by only giving the 95% answer is that you set up a learner to believe they've encountered an error when they see the less common – but still acceptable – form crop up. Were I the learner, I'd rather be given a more comprehensive answer than an abridged one.

Comment: @J.R.: Like I say - each to their own. I've no reason to suppose anyone, learner or no, would have trouble *understanding* the uncommon variants. After all, we can all read stuff with spelling mistakes. But if I were learning another language, I'd want to be able to produce acceptable utterances myself without having to remember which of half-a-dozen variants I'd learnt was the standard version applicable in all contexts.

Comment: @J.R. I would suggest that "a four hours trip" or "a four hour's trip" are archaic. I certainly don't see them day-to-day. The two links you provide as examples of non-archaic books use the "four hour's trip" form, which is current and correct, as you imply.

Answer (score 3):

> It was a pleasant four hour journey from Nashik to Pune.

...is correct. "Four hours" would definitely be wrong here. But bear in mind you may also see:

> It was four hours' pleasant journey from Nashik to Pune.

The difference is the "a" - in the first example, you're talking about "a journey". In the second, the focus is on "four hours" and how you spent them. Both are correct, and idiomatic, but do not mix them.

If you wish to use the second, don't forget the apostrophe. :)

Comment: +1 for "both are correct .. but do not mix them".